# Cshell: to use "shift" but for an argument in the middle

Tags: csh, tcsh

I want my Cshell script to process through my $argv list, but to cherry-pick through that list. For example:

```
@ i = 1
while ( $i <= $#argv )
  if ($argv[$i] == "--ignore-externals") then
    set svnargs = ( $svnargs $argv[$i] )
    shift $argv[1]
  else
    @ i = $i + 1
  endif
end
```

... but "shift" doesn't work like that. What's the best approach?

Comment: did you have a look at getopt?

Comment: I am a nube to getopt. It looks like it wouldn't work because it's not directly part of the shell, but then again, there was a good example I found.  I'm not sure how to use it for my case.

Comment: `shift n`, where n is an integer, right? to get rid of a specific argument in your list, just assign it the `""` null(ish) string, i.e. `argv[1]=""` or `argv[$i]=""`. I don't have a csh to play with anymore, so can't confirm that this will work, but `shift $argv[1]` won't work. Keep playing with it, or better yet, switch to `ksh` or `bash` or `zsh` or ... ? Having worked at a place where `csh` was the default shell for 1000+ users, I know that switching may not be as practical as it sounds to us converts. Good luck.